# Calling web methods sequentially with javascript

Tags: javascript, asmx, webmethod

I am trying to call web methods sequentially (on success, call the next web method and so on). Unfortunately, the sequence stops when two methods have been called while no exception is thrown.

The client side code looks something like:

```
        window.myJSObj = {
              'Function1': function () {
                  WebMethods.WebMethod1($('#inputVal').val(), this.Function2, this.CallErrorFunction);
              },
              'Function2': function () {
                  WebMethods.WebMethod2($('#inputVal').val(), this.Function3, this.CallErrorFunction);
              },
              'Function3': function () {
                  WebMethods.WebMethod3($('#inputVal').val(), this.CallSuccessFunction, this.CallErrorFunction);
              },
              'CallSuccessFunction': function () {
                  console.log('success');
              },
              'CallErrorFunction': function () {
                  console.log('Error');
              },
          }
```

When I am calling `myJSObj.Function1()` it runs and on success it calls `myJSObj.Function2()`. `myJSObj.Function2()` runs but `myJSObj.Function3()` is never called and no JS error is thrown. The sequence only calls up to two JS functions (and associated web methods) and stops. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error in the console? I think the problem is that `this` isn't what you wanted/expected it to be within Function2,  so then `this.Function3` is undefined. (One way to fix this is with .bind().)

Comment: @nnnnnn, spot on. I did not think to check this behavior. In the first call, `this` refers to `myJSObj` but in Function2, `this` is the `window` object. Any idea why this is happening? Btw, I replaced all instances of `this` with `myJSObj` to fix it.